# Getting a tab list from the console in Qutebrowser

Tags: linux, qutebrowser

We want to create a script that shows the music I am playing from [Spotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotify) in a web browser.

Is there a way I can get the names of the opened tabs in Qutebrowser from the terminal?

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, there is a tag called _qutebrowser_ :)